# How to grab and store last string of url in Cypress

Tags: testing, url, automation, cypress

I have a url https://www.xxx/xxxx/xxx/1234.  I just need the numbers 1234 and store them in my global variable.

```js
cy.log(this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last part of the URL (the slug) is most easily obtained like this

```js
const url = 'https://www.xxx/xxxx/xxx/1234'

const slug = url.split('/').pop()

expect(slug).to.eq('1234')    // ok
```

Where you are going to store it depends on how you are going to use it (i.e in the same test, across tests in the same spec file, across spec files).

You mention global variables, that would be something like

```js
let slug;  // define empty global variable

it('gets the slug', () => {
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.url().then(url => slug = url.split('/').pop())

  //log in same test
  cy.then(() => {             // MUST use .then() to avoid "closure" issues
    cy.log(slug)              // logs 1234
  })
})

it('uses slug', () => {

  // log in different test
  cy.log(slug)             // logs 1234
})
```

Comment: Hi Janet, I tried the global var way and it looks like the slug does not get assigned because the cy.log(slug) print just 'log' with nothing in it.

Comment: Take a look at the placement of `cy.log()` in my answer - in the same test, you must use a `.then()` but in the second test, it's a different execution block so `cy.log()` works without the `cy.then()` wrapper.

Comment: Correct, it would be the same issue using `Cypress.env()` to store the value, because of the way `cy.log()` works. It doesn't matter where you store the value, you must always wait for the commands to run first.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `cy.url()` to yield the current URL that Cypress is on. You can then set it as a Cypress environment variable, using `Cypress.env()`.

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
  Cypress.env('href', url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
});
```

You could then reference that variable later on with the following:

```js
cy.log(Cypress.env('href'));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! However, how would I then use that for later on? Would this work? cy.log(href); ---> //Yields 1234 as a string ?????